# Why can't I add a lookup filter on the product field on assets?

Tags: lookup-filter, asset

When I go to edit asset metadata I can bring up the (empty) list of lookup filters but I can't add one because there are no buttons to do so.

Only some of our products should be selectable as assets (some are services and we use the asset object as part of a stock control system, so intangible products should be left out), but I cannot find for the life of me how to add that as a lookup filter.

Also, I can't seem to add assets from the asset product view. Is this something salesforce decided nobody would ever need by themselves, along with quite a lot else it would seem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at my current developer edition org, and my pre-release Summer 14 org and both allow me to add a new lookup filter. This sounds like some kind of bug, or glitch that you have run into. Perhaps try clearing the cache on your browser and retrying that config page, trying with a different browser, etc. to establish whether it is a problem with salesforce, or with your local browser, and then contact support.

In any case, adding product lookup field filters in the asset object should, and (at least in my case) does work the same as everywhere else.